# Trying to get rid of unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, android, generics, type-erasure

I have a method which makes use of some generics.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <Param1 extends Fragment, Param2 extends Context, Result> Optional<Result> useContextFromFragment(
final WeakReference<Param1> reference,
final UseContext<Result, Param2> task) {

        final Param1 fragment;
        if (reference == null || (fragment = reference.get()) == null)
            return Optional.absent();

        final Activity activity = fragment.getActivity();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing())
            return Optional.absent();

        return Optional.fromNullable(task.work((Param2) activity));
    }
```

Activity is a class which extends Context.
Is there now way to get rid of the unchecked cast ?

Comment: What's `Activity`? Also please note that the convention for type parameter names is a single uppercase letter (or maybe two).

Comment: Activity is a class. I can get an instance of it from fragment object. Activity extends Context. Activity, Context and Fragment are android specific classes, not that its imp here.

Comment: Well, in that case your cast is indeed unsafe. It is true that `Param2 extends Context` and `Activity extends Context` too, but there's no guarantee that `Param2 extends Activity`. If you know for a fact that `Param2 extends Activty`, declare it as such.

Comment: I would also question the use of type parameters in this case, it seems like it really doesn't buy you anything here. You could probably just have `public static <R> Optional<R> useContextFromFragment(
final WeakReference<Fragment> reference,
final UseContext<R, Context> task)`

Comment: Sometime, I need to pass Activity and other times Context in UseContext, was trying to avoid creating 2 separate methods.

Comment: Ok, I just realized I was making a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since `Param1` and `Param2` are two independent type parameters, there can be no guarantee that `WeakReference<Param1>.get().getActivity()` is actually of type `Param2`.

You are taking that on faith.

---

Unrelated, but as @biziclop commented, the convention is for type parameters to be a single uppercase letter, or maybe two.

Your method should be:

```
public static <F extends Fragment, C extends Context, R> Optional<R> useContextFromFragment(
        final WeakReference<F> reference,
        final UseContext<R, C> task) {
```

Comment: Was afraid of that. Not that it will ever throw an error. This has something to do with type erasure, right ?

Comment: @Dexter No, it has to do with the fact that `Param1` and `Param2` are independent.